# Retrieve information from a website and store it in an excel sheet

Tags: java

I want to make a program that takes and isbn number and searches the web for the information about the book assosciated with that number and then store that information in an excel sheet. I am not sure how to go about doing this.

I was thinking about making a Java program that uses the JSoup library to retrieve information from a url and then simply putting that information in a text file so the user can manually copy and paste it into an excel sheet, but there has to be a direct way. Any help would be appreciated. Thankyou.

Comment: What do you mean by direct way? already written program?

Comment: possible duplicate of [create excel using Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305827/create-excel-using-java)

Comment: No i mean that instead of storing the parsed information from the website in a text file and then copy-pasting it into an excel file, is there a way to directly store that information in the .xls file? I tried opening an excel file in regular Notepad and it had a whole bunch of weird ascii characters. So simply creating a text file and then changing its extension to .xls probably wont work.

Comment: Thank you for the link Greg. I'll use the JExcel library for this.

Comment: @user1022223- Please don't edit the title of this question to contained the word "Solved."  Instead, mark your favorite answer as accepted, so that the system considers it resolved.

Answer (score 0):

For getting the info,

> http://code.google.com/apis/books/docs/getting-started.html
>
> http://bibwild.wordpress.com/2008/03/19/think-you-can-use-amazon-api-for-library-service-book-covers/

Then you can use [Java Excel API](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) to enter to the excel sheet. 
You can find the tutorial about that here http://www.andykhan.com/jexcelapi/tutorial.html

Comment: Thanks so much shady. This is really useful stuff. I appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 0):

http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html

apache project for manipulating excel in java